# What is the difference between a Function Template and a Delegate?

Tags: c#, c++

I have arrived at a point in my self-taught studies where I am not fully grasping what a `delegate` in C# is useful for. Additionally, on a whim, I decided to take a look at an intro to C++ site and I came across `function templates`.

Maybe I'm comparing apples and oranges here, but I understood a `delegate` to be a sort of template for a function that would be defined at run-time. Is this true? If so, how does that differ from a function template in C++?

Is it possible to see (realistic) examples of each in use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A delegate is a way of taking a member function of some object, and creating a...thing that can be called independently.

In other words, if you have some object A, with some member function `F`, that you'd normally call as something like: `A.F(1);`, a delegate is a single entity that you can (for example) pass as a parameter, that acts as a proxy for that object/member function, so when the delegate is invoked, it's equivalent to invoking that member function of that object.

It's a way of taking existing code, and...packaging it to make it easier to use in a fairly specific way (though I feel obliged to add, that 'way' is quite versatile so delegates can be extremely useful).

A C++ function template is a way of *generating* functions. It specifies some set of actions to take, but does not specify the specific type of object on which those actions will happen. The specification is at a syntactic level, so (for example) I can specify adding two things together to get a third item that's their sum. If I apply that to numbers, it sums like you'd expect. If I do the same with strings, it'll typically concatenate the strings. This is because (syntactically) the template just specifies something like `a+b`, but `+` is defined to do addition of numbers, and concatenation of strings.

Looked at slightly differently, a function template just specifies the skeleton for some code. The rest of that code's body is "filled in" based on the type, when you instantiate the template over some specific type.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ terms a C# delegate combines an object pointer and a member function pointer into one callable entity, which calls the member function on the pointed to object.

You can do about the same with `std::bind` and `std::function`.

Before C++11 there was a short flurry of articles on how to do very efficient delegates in C++. `std::function` is a very reasonable compromise and may even attain those levels of efficiency.

---

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

// Here `function<void()>` serves as a "delegate" type.
void callback_on( function<void()> const f )
{
    f();
}

struct S
{
    int x;
    void foo() const { cout << x << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    S o = {42};
    callback_on( bind( &S::foo, &o ) );
}
```